# Get error when using findBy() in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, grails-controller

I have a GSP page:

```
<g:if test="freelancer">
        <g:each in="${ freelancer }" var="freelance">
            <a href="${ createLink(controller:'user', action:'homepage', id:freelance.user.username) }">${ freelance.firstName }</a>
        </g:each>
</g:if>
```

and an action:

```
def homepage() {
    println(params.id)
    def user = User.find{
        username == params.id
    }
    if(user){
        println(user.username + "!")
        return[user:user]
    }
}
```

and a welcome page:

```
<body>
    Welcome ${ user.username }
</body>
```

in the first GSP page I get firstName link, and when I click on it to view his homepage I get an error:

```
Cannot get property 'username' on null object
```

But in the Console of my IDE, `println(params.id)` prints a username, BUT with square brackets. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: So params.id result to be a list in homepage action? Can you post your domains source code?

Comment: We'd also probbaly need to see how you're populating your freelancer collection and passing that to the view.  Your User.find is overkill.  Just do User.findByUsername(params.id).  I'm also surprised your g:if works.  You don't have ${} around freelancer for your test.  Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your "homepage" action try

`def user = User.find{ it.username == params.id }` instead of

`def user = User.find{ username == params.id }`

Answer (score 0):

This is my User domain class:

```
class User {
String username
String passwordHash
byte[] passwordSalt
Profile profile

static hasMany = [ roles: Role, permissions: String ]

static constraints = {
    profile(nullable:false)
    username(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true, size:3..15)
    passwordHash(nullable:false, blank:false, minSize:6)
}

static mapping = {
    profile lazy:false
}
```

In the g:if tag I put freelancer to the brackets and changed to `User.findByUsername()`. But there is the same error. I don't want params.id as list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to use brackets in your  tag. That's number one.

```
<g:if test="${freelancer}">

</g:if>
```

Otherwise, the *groovy truth* will always evaluate a non-empty string as true, thus your test will be flawed.

Also, I would use the g:link instead of html 'a' tag.

```
    <g:each in="${ freelancer }" var="freelance">
        <g:link controller='user', action='homepage', id="${freelance.user.username}">
            ${freelance.firstName}
        </g:link>
    </g:each>
```

As a suggestion, think of using User.findByUsername() instead of find closure.

Let us know if that works. ;)